# does boost::asio co_spawn create an actual thread?

Tags: boost-asio, c++20

When looking through `boost asio co_spawn` documentation (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/co_spawn/overload6.html), I see this statement, "Spawn a new coroutined-based thread of execution", however my understanding is that `co_spawn` does not create an actual thread, but uses threads that are part of the `boost::asio::io_context` pool. It's a "coroutine-based thread of execution" in a sense, that this coroutine would be a root of all coroutines that are spawned from inside this one

Is my understanding correct here or an actual thread is created whenever `co_spawn` is used like this:

```cpp
::boost::asio::co_spawn(io_ctx, [&] -> ::boost::asio::awaitable<void> {
 // do something
}, ::boost::asio::detached);
```

thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does not. See [The Proactor Design Pattern: Concurrency Without Threads](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html) and https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html

What does `detached` mean/do? The [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/detached_t.html) says:

> The detached_t class is used to indicate that an asynchronous operation is detached. That is, **there is no completion handler waiting for the operation's result**.

It comes down to writing a no-op handler but (a) less work (b) more room for the library to optimize.

---

Another angle to look at this from is this: if the execution context for the executor (`io_ctx`) is never run/polled, nothing will ever happen. As always in boost, **you** decide where you run the service (whether you use threads e.g.)